# How to merge 2 rows into 1 row with 2 different columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I would like to merge 2 or 3 row into 1 row like below.

Original chart:

| CaseNr | AccType | Vehicle | Model | VehicleMass |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | PassengerCar | A1 | 1217 |
| A | 1 | Train | Train | 99999 |
| B | 2 | PassengerCar | B7 | 1400 |
| B | 2 | Train | Train | 99999 |
| C | 3 | PassengerCar | C2 | 1295 |

Modified chart that I want:

| CaseNr | AccType | Vehicle_1 | Vehicle_2 | Model_1 | Model_2 | VehicleMass_1 | Vehicle Mass_2 | MainFac |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | PassengerCar | Train | A1 | Train | 1217 | 99999 | 5 |
| B | 2 | PassengerCar | Train | B7 | Train | 1400 | 99999 | 6 |
| C | 3 | PassengerCar | NaN | C2 | NaN | 1295 | NaN | 2 |

As you could notice the chart, the data field include vehicle crash information.
Therefore, 1, 2, or 3 vehicles could be involved in one accident case.

I searched all `merge` options but I could not find how to do this.

Comment: "I searched all 'merge' options but I could not find how to do this." Proof of this?

Comment: you need to create a custom window then pivot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pivot` to reshape your data. This is called reshaping to wide and not merging.

```
df1 = df.assign(name = df.groupby('CaseNr').cumcount() + 1).pivot(['CaseNr', 'AccType'], 'name')
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x:f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
df1.reset_index()

  CaseNr  AccType     Vehicle_1  ... Model_2 VehicleMass_1 VehicleMass_2
0      A        1  PassengerCar  ...   Train        1217.0       99999.0
1      B        2  PassengerCar  ...   Train        1400.0       99999.0
2      C        3  PassengerCar  ...     NaN        1295.0           NaN
```

If you have `janitor` installed you can do:

```
import janitor
df.assign(name = df.groupby('CaseNr').cumcount() + 1).pivot_wider(['CaseNr', 'AccType'], 'name')

  CaseNr  AccType     Vehicle_1  ... Model_2 VehicleMass_1 VehicleMass_2
0      A        1  PassengerCar  ...   Train        1217.0       99999.0
1      B        2  PassengerCar  ...   Train        1400.0       99999.0
2      C        3  PassengerCar  ...     NaN        1295.0           NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

using `cumcount` and `.unstack`

```
s = df.groupby(["CaseNr", "AccType"]).cumcount()

df.set_index([s + 1, "CaseNr", "AccType"]).unstack(0)

# if you must flatten your multi index - better to have it imo.

df1.columns = [f"{x}_{y}" for x, y in df1.columns.to_flat_index()]


print(df1)

                   Vehicle_1 Vehicle_2 Model_1 Model_2  VehicleMass_1  VehicleMass_2
CaseNr AccType
A      1        PassengerCar     Train      A1   Train         1217.0        99999.0
B      2        PassengerCar     Train      B7   Train         1400.0        99999.0
C      3        PassengerCar       NaN      C2     NaN         1295.0            NaN
```